# Is there a circuit that outputs high indefinitely once one high is received by the circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, comparator, sequential-logic

Apologies if the question is worded oddly/weirdly, but specifically I have a comparator with an unstable output which I know could be fixed with hysteresis, but I would rather just have some circuit output high indefinitely once the correct conditions are met and the comparator outputs high once. I know I could use a microcontroller and program it to keep track using memory, but I was just wondering if there was something simpler I could use. I'm still an electonics newbie, so any help/pointers/or even just the name of such a circuit would be much appreciated!

If it helps, I could go more in depth on what my circuit is/draw up a schematic, but I didn't want to drag this on for too long. Much thanks for reading this!

Comment: This is a memory cell or latch a.k.a. "register".  It can be state or level controlled input with a separate reset a.k.a. RS flip flip or it can be an edge sensitive D Flip Flop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIWxFR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basically, once you give the input '1', the output of the OR gate will be '1'. Now, what you need to do is give the *EN* pin '1' so the DFF will detect a rising edge.

Once that is done, the output of the DFF, *Q*, will constantly output '1'.

---

Another solution, if you don't want to have two input signals, is to use a resistor-capacitor for time delay. Once your input goes high, after a while your clk/enable pin will go high as well, thus saving you the need for another input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNidPa.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use a rising edge re-settable D-flip-flop with the D connected high . Your signal goes into the clock input. If you have an active low reset you can use the standard R-C delay.

When a high (rising edge) comes into the clock pin the Q output becomes high and will stay that way until the register is reset.

The schematic below is a bit incomplete as I could not find a symbol for a D-register with reset.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUoMyy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsHaAU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a latch with logic =1 5V when Vin > Vref and stays there until a power cycle.

- 90% Hysteresis (overkill) controlled by R1/(R1+R2)
- R3 is just in case it is open collector comparator.
- This is inverted to what you asked for so high is fault or over threshold.
- If you swap the inputs for Vref and 0~Vin then it is inverting (low in= Hi ok out)

  - but then you want to swap R2,R1 values and threshold then R2/(R1+R2) * Vref
- so with R1=10k and R2= 100k to have ~+-9% hysteresis. (1/11=9%)